# PHP loop adding Array[0] instead of data to MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which coaches can enter in multiple pitchers for games.  The form allows users to add rows as needed and looks like this:

```
<tr><td><select name="pitcherteam[]" size="1">
<option>PLEASE SELECT TEAM
<option>Team 1
<option>Team 2
<option>Team 3
</select></td><td>
<input type=text size=50 name="pitcher[]"></td><td>
<select name="pitcherage[]" size="1">
<option>AGE
<option>8
<option>9
</select></td>
<td><input type="text" size=3 name="pitcherpitches[]"></td></tr>
```

The php code I am using loops through the pitchers and if they are not blank does an insert into the mysql db:

```
$size_array = count($_POST['pitcher']); 
for ($i=0; $i<$size_array; $i++){ 
    if($_POST['pitcher'][$i] != ''){
    $sql2="INSERT INTO pitchcounts (pitcherteam, pitcher, pitcherage, pitches)
VALUES
    ('$_POST[date]','$_POST[pitcherteam][$i]','$_POST[pitcher][$i]','
$_POST[pitcherage][$i]','$_POST[pitches][$i]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2))
      {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
} 
}
```

The loop is actually updating the db - BUT - instead of the values from the form - it's putting in zeros and array markers like this:

```
pitcherteam pitcher pitcherage  pitches
Array[0]    Array[0]    0   0
Array[1]    Array[1]    0   0
Array[3]    Array[3]    0   0
```

Any ideas on what's going on?  Thanks!

Comment: check the query before executing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate your strings and variables!

```
$date = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['date'])); //example variable clean
$sql2=" INSERT INTO
            `pitchcounts`
            (`pitcherteam`, `pitcher`, `pitcherage`, `pitches`)
        VALUES
            ('".$date."','".$_POST['pitcherteam'][$i]."','".$_POST['pitcher'][$i]."'
            ,'".$_POST['pitcherage'][$i]."','".$_POST['pitches'][$i]."')";
```

You should also **clean your inputs** - you should never put `$_POST` data straight into a database.

When dealing with cleaning arrays, there is no need to loop through each value applying the cleaning method individually, for those cases you can make use of `array_map`

```
function clean($val)
{
     return trim(strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string($val)));
}
$pitchers = array_map('clean',$_POST['pitcher']);
```

However, as mentioned by HamZa below, the best way of dealing with situations like this is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#example-1750). Though depending on your experience, this may require some extra time and effort in order to convert your code over to that style.

Table and field names should also be surrounded with backticks `` ` `` to avoid conflict with reserved keywords

In addition to cleaning variables, you will also do well to validate the inputs as well. Other specialised cleaning methods are available as well for example, for a numeric field call `intval` or `floatval`, as other string fixing methods would be unnecessary

Comment: It's entertaining to watch a completely buggy code being updated and fixed in real time :P

Comment: lolwut ? Why don't you show him the "right" way by using prepared statements ?

Comment: @MightyPork Yea, noticed something every time I saved an edit lol

Comment: @HamZa If he can't handle string concatenation, I'll let him off using this method for now

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Well you could fix where he went wrong and show him the right way. Also what about using `array_map` and not using concatenation at all `$str = "demo {$_POST['foo']} demo";`

Comment: @HamZa because validation should be performed on the input data, which will be much easier and more legible, if put into new variables, with shorter names - though indeed, for arrays `array_map` can be very handy. Again, legibility is a key reason to use concatenation instead of "text {$var} text"

Comment: Why are you so sarcastic about a "right" way of using prepared statements?

Comment: @VladimirHraban Not sure where you've got sarcasm from... certainly not meant to be sarcastic. I'm just making sure I don't give the OP too much to change, hence only referencing the preferred method

Comment: @VladimirHraban I'm not being sarcastic, prepared statements won't protect you from everything. Please read my early [answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39310/sql-injection-can-bypass-login-but-not-drop-table/39328#39328) on Security SE for some insight.

Comment: @VladimirHraban Well no of course they don't, hence my note about validating the inputs and not just cleaning. (for the record I hadn't said anything about you being sarcastic, was just confused about how my answer had come across as sarcastic)

Comment: Anyway @all, we're going well above and beyond what the OP asked. They now know what to be looking into, let's not turn this into a Community Wiki comment chain!

Comment: Thanks for all of the useful comments and suggestions - it is greatly appreciated!